# Do PCs facing a group of harpies have to make multiple saving throws against their song?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, saving-throw

Do PCs facing a group of harpies using **Luring song** at the same time make a wisdom saving throw for *each* individual source of the melody or is it a single roll, considering it's the same ability?

Here are the relevant parts of the ability's description (MM, p. 181, emphasis mine) :

> **Luring Song.** The harpy sings a magical melody. Every humanoid and giant within 300 feet of the harpy that can hear the song must succeed on a DC 11 Wisdom saving throw or be charmed until the song ends. [...] While charmed by the harpy, a target is incapacitated and **ignores the songs of other harpies**.  [...] If a creature's saving throw is successful, the effect ends on it. A target that successfully saves **is immune to this harpy's song** for the next 24 hours.

My reading is that once PCs have made a successful check against one harpy, they are immune to this harpy's song for 24 hours, but must still make saves against every other singer until they fail on one roll or succeed on every last one of them. Is this right? It seems powerful to me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your reading is correct, PCs have to make a save against every harpy's song individually. You've already quoted the relevant line:

> A target that successfully saves is immune to this harpy's song for the next 24 hours.

It says "**this** harpy's song" specifically, not just "harpy's song" or even "this ability". And given the note about other harpy songs earlier in the paragraph, the writers clearly had multiple harpy situations in mind.

As far as it being powerful is concerned, it's not really an issue. The save is a fairly easy one which characters are given multiple chances to succeed at. On top of this, it requires specific situations to be dangerous, and offers an extra save if it is.

Answer (score -1):

**Rules as written**: each harpy is singing its own song with its own effect.

**Common sense**: if a group of people try singing different songs at the same time, unless there's some sort of lyrical harmony, they're going to make each other mess up. If the harpies are singing in harmony then it's not multiple songs but rather one song being sung by multiple harpies.

Make the ruling that fits your preference.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the tour and visit the help to see how a Q&A site works, and how to write a supported answer. I've made a modest edit to upgrade your answer, but you are free to edit it again to go back to your original answer, or to improve it further.

Comment: This is an interesting alternative answer, home-brew/house-rule that multiple harpies singing the same song would up its DC but be a singular affect would account for the increased difficulty while simultaneously decreasing number of dice rolls

Comment: Your common sense piece would be improved by including a point about when a DM grants advantage/disadvantage based on a situation.  That would better draw on rules based support for this answer.

Answer (score -20):

Each player needs to make the check once per encounter. Assume that harpies together sing a similar song and the charm would only need to be overcome once.